# 'NoneType' object has no attritube '__getitem__'

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I noticed my code wasn't running properly. But I have declared it for the lines.

It says that:
line 28, in  
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines [0]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
# importthe necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2

#initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (720,240)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(720,240))

#allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

#capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    #grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    #and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #image = cv2.medianBlur (gray, 0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,250,apertureSize = 3)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=10,maxLineGap=100)
    #ret, th1 =cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
        cv2.line(crop_img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.line(empty,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)


    # Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
    cv2.line(image,(0,240),(50,180),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.line(image,(320,240),(270,180),(255,0,0),2)

    #show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Original", image)
    cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    #clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    #if the 'q' key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

What shall I do to fix this error?

Comment: ` TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getitem'`  it means that the `lines` is `None`. You should check it because use `lines[0]`

Comment: `print(lines)`...what do you see?

Comment: I got many numbers [[[4 153 136 42 ] [5 157 139 44][ 17 146 139 44]]]. It stopped when the same error come in. Apparently when it doesn't detect any line, it will appear an error

Answer (score -1):

It seems like this line returns `None`:

`lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=10,maxLineGap=100)`

And then on the next line `for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]` fails, due to `lines` is `None`. You need to make sure now that `cv2.HoughLinesP()` returns correct data or add a check to check like:

`if lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    ...`

Comment: It did get datas. If I didn't point my camera to a line, it will show an error and automatically stop the operation. I want it to not stop even if no lines are detected.

Comment: okay, now it has a new bug.  Value Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()